# Ef Core: ToHashSetAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have noticed that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Linq extension methods dose not contain ToHashSet **Async** version, I'm assuming the right & safe way to materialize the object is HashSet since it protects against duplication, did I missed something? if it's so important why there is no Async version of it?

Comment: It is wrong assumption. Have you overridden `Equals` and `GetHasCode` for every model entity? I think not. If you have duplicates, probably you have written bad LINQ query.

Comment: If you have duplicate results from your query, then either the query is malformed, or you truly have duplicate entities in your database. Either way, address the issue, not it's symptoms

Comment: Feel free to `ToList().ToHashSet()` to find out why.. (It's not as useful as you think it is)

Comment: What if I'm adding a duplicate entity to the collection ? wouldn't it be nice to not add it ?

Comment: Then you should specify that with a distinct.

Comment: In the database, each entry has a unique identifier. To there are no real 'duplicates'. And there are many situations in which you want to clone data: i.e. make a duplicate (with exception of the unique ID). The Async Linq statements are statements which can be performed on the server, thus can be awaited until the server returns. I don't know of any servers that can produce a C# HashSet.

Comment: p.s. "adding a duplicate entity" and "materialize the object" are two quite different things. Please focus on one.

Comment: I'm confused by all those comments and the main answer. A list is a way of representing a set. It has a specific implementation that makes it easy to iterate on, and that's it. Whereas a hashset has an implicit contract : No duplicates. Even if my db query returns unique items *by design*, then I want C# (and the consumers of my code) to be guaranteed once and for all that there are no duplicates. If I tell Linq to FIRST convert the result to a List (async) and only THEN build a Hashset from it, for all I know it could be twice more expensive -- I'm not supposed to look at the implementations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code, your tables are represented as a DbSet which is an IListSource.

IListSource has one method:

```cs
IList GetList();
```

So everything that's returned from EntityFrameworkCore is an IList; an indexable, non-unique bag of values. Whereas a HashSet, being much faster to access, is a unique, non-indexed bag of values. Equality Comparison determines its uniqueness, and anything more than a few columns starts to get really expensive to calculate.

Whilst you might think it'd be more performant to go straight to a HashSet, if that's what you need, the data is already a List. ToListAsync() just calls a rose a rose, and loads the data. Then you can HashSet it if needed.